# Godot Rigidbody2D collision detection issues

Tags: collision-detection, gdscript, rigid-bodies

I've been having problems detecting when 2 Rigid Bodies collide in Godot (specifically a falling pill and a floor that is frozen in place). I need to delete the pill when it contacts the floor. I have already tried fixing the following things:

1. Setting contact monitor to true and setting Max contacts to 100
2. re-linking the Rigidbody2D body_entered signal to the code
3. printing when it detects a collision (nothing was ever printed to console.)

However, for some reason, if I shift the code over to the pill, it works perfectly fine the other way around. (When the pill contacts the floor, it deletes the floor)

The code for the floor:
[(code is in gdscript)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd261.png)

The signal: [signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i7vH.png)

The floor settings: [floor settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XE7l.png)

The pill settings: [pill settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4hCc.png)

The error messages [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCQdY.png)